# How to center two divs when they move / stack under one another?

Tags: css

Note that yes there are similar questions here, but I tried what they have mentioned as solutions, and I still can't get my items centered. I have stuck text-align: center, display:inline-block; margin: 0 auto and width: 100% in multiple places and I still can't get the items to display centered.

O.k. With that out of the way, here is the code and then the explanation below:

```
<h4  style="margin-bottom:-15px"><strong>The Item Item Below:</strong></h4>
    <img  style="float:left;width:100%; max-width: 408px; height:100%; max-height: 134px; background-color:red; margin-top:40px; margin-right:20px"

       src="http://s25.postimg.org/kbrcsousf/408x134.png"> <span  style="float:left; margin:0 auto; max-width:100%">
      <p  style="text-align:center; text-decoration: underline"><strong> Works
          with these Things:</strong></p>
      <div  style="float:left;max-width:100%; width:160px;text-align:center;margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:20px">
        <div  style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);"><span  style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Flowers
              A<br>
            </strong></span></div>
        <div  style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);"><img  src="http://s25.postimg.org/i8gxl0uzf/140x124.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div  style="float:left;max-width:100%; width:230px;text-align:center;">
        <div  style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);"><span  style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Flowers
              B<br>
            </strong></span></div>
        <div  style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"><img  src="http://s25.postimg.org/a48tga8kf/209x112.png"></div>
      </div>
    </span>
```

Now the explanation:
So, I first started out with the first image on a line by itself and then had the bottom two pairs of divs below it. I figured I was wasting a bit too much horizontal space, so I placed the two pairs of divs next to / to the right of the "408x134" image by placing float:left in that image and enclosing the two pairs of divs with a span tag and placing float:left in it.

I am designing this with responsiveness / mobile in mind and am trying to avoid using @media for now.

So, when one reduces the size of their screen on their browser horizontally, the two items to the right drop down as a pair below the "408x134" image, which is what I want. As the screen gets even smaller, the two items below get separated, with the "209 x 112" image going underneath the "140 x 124" image. (Well, that and the div label above each one of them).

This is what I want. **However, the final part I can't get is that I want those two pairs of divs to be centered. How can I do that? If you can give an explanation of your solution also, that would be great, so that I can finally understand how to fix this problem in the future or avoid it in the first place.** Now I realize that the first pair of divs -- Flowers A and "140 x 124" won't be exactly centered as I have placed a right margin, and that is so that there can be some space when they are next to one another horizontally and also under one another when they are stacked on a smaller screen. For that to be centered I think I will have to use @media tags to remove/resize the margin and add a line break or another div or something.

Comment: Is there any reason you do not want to use media queries? Other wise you will have to use javascript

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below:

```
 <h4  style="margin-bottom:-15px"><strong>The Item Item Below:</strong></h4>
    <img  style="float:left;width:100%; max-width: 408px; height:100%; max-height: 134px; background-color:red; margin-top:40px; margin-right:20px"

       src="http://s25.postimg.org/kbrcsousf/408x134.png"> <span  style="float:left; margin:0 auto; max-width:100%">
      <p  style="text-align:center; text-decoration: underline"><strong> Works
          with these Things:</strong></p>
          <center>
      <div  style="margin: 0 auto;display:inline-block;max-width:100%; width:160px;text-align:center;margin-right:20px;">
        <div  style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);"><span  style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Flowers
              A<br>
            </strong></span></div>
        <div  style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);"><img  src="http://s25.postimg.org/i8gxl0uzf/140x124.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div  style="margin: 0 auto; display:inline-block;max-width:100%; width:230px;text-align:center;">
        <div  style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);"><span  style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Flowers
              B<br>
            </strong></span></div>
        <div  style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"><img  src="http://s25.postimg.org/a48tga8kf/209x112.png"></div>
      </div>
    </span>
    </center>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If you add back margin-bottom:20px to the div that surrounds Flowers A & "140 x 124" image and add vertical-align:top to the div that surrounds Flowers B & "209 x 112" image, you get exactly what I had plus the centering that you were able to do. I tried adding the center tag but wasn't getting it to work, but that's because I didn't delete the span tag holding everything nor did the other changes you did. Since the center tag is not supported in HTML 5, I changed it to `<div style="text-align:center"></div>`, which is working fine. I also wanted an explanation, but I am

Comment: Oh ok, glad that it worked well for you. I know the code above needs some adjustment. Thanks for the comment Rolo! Glad that you figured it out! :)

Comment: very happy for a working code. So, to add some explanation: 1. You left `float:left` in the `img` tag and in the `span` tag I had surrounding the two pairs of divs I had, 2. You replaced `float:left` on my 2 main divs with `margin: 0 auto;display:inline-block`. The style `vertical-align:top` had to the added to the div that surrounds Flowers B & "209 x 112" image because `float:left` was removed and it by default includes top vertical alignment. Hopefully these extra notes help others who are new to CSS and trying to make sense of how to arrange / layout items.

Comment: Correction to my first comment as I can't edit any longer: The `span` tag was not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried looking at your HTML and I think you're missing a few tags. Additionally, best practice is to not have CSS styles inline with HTML; you typically want to have CSS in a separate stylesheet.  Getting past all that, I think you need to know some things about the elements and properties you are working with.

A `div` is block-level element by default, which takes up 100% width of its container (parent) unless you add some other overriding style to it. One option (which you've selected) is `float:left;` which will get this element to act sort of like an inline element (like a `span` or `img`) except it will always try to align itself with the left of the container; no matter the type of alignment you've set to the container.

What I will recommend in your case is setting the image container `div` elements to `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;`, that way it will be affected by a parent's `text-align:center;` property and when there's no room for all of the `div` elements to be in a row, they will fall down underneath but be aligned in the middle.  You don't currently seem to have a container element but your setup should probably look something like this:

```css
#container{
  text-align:center;
}

#container .imgwrap{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="imgwrap"><img src="#"/></div>
  <div class="imgwrap"><img src="#"/></div>
  <div class="imgwrap"><img src="#"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was also looking for that and will have to read up more on it. As for your code, I want the two main divs on the right to stay intact as much as possible because I have one header for both of them, and therefore, I never want one to be left behind with the first image. They go together always and when they have to split, they are still separated from the first image. I do believe I was able to previously do what you have laid out though as I was able to to this for two divs side by side. Nonetheless, I will keep this in mind should I need to refer to it.

Answer (score -2):

My off the cuff: divs in my limited experience defeat the point of css. Second, there is script to detect screen size and allow u to provide separate css based on that. Thats how I've played it.